# User scores are out of order in the "week" tab

Tags: support, caching, score

When a new week recently began, I noticed something strange in the "week" tab:

[image]

I know this is just a <del>bug</del> "feature" with caching, but I wonder why an update to the scores on this page does not also just apply the correct order. Why are the two types of updates separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sorting can take a lot more time than just updating scores

So, a user earns some reputation. To update the displayed reputation gain, the website only has to update a variable or two somewhere, one of which is then accessed when you look at that page.

To update the order, however, takes significantly longer. I don't know exactly how they store their stuff, but it could easily take a dozen orders of magnitude longer to sort the user list rather than just update one user. This is especially important on sites like SO, where there are 4.8 million users.